# What is the difference between In-App Messaging and In-App Messaging Display in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I recently check the dependencies of Firebase for Android and notice that there is a new dependency named In-App Messaging Display? What is the difference between this two? The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is all the same.[image: o]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inapp-messaging-display` is a sub dependency and the `inappmessaging` is the parent dependency.

It is the same as adding google play service:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
```

which will give you all the libraries under the google play service, but it is not recommended to use.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: So does it means that 'in-app messaging' has other sub dependency? Sorry I still don't get it, are they planning to create sub dependencies in the future? Is there any official documentation for this?

Comment: Child library I mean, yes they did that in case they create more libraries related to inapp messaging. It literally the same as if you add the whole play-service you would get all the libraries that are in play-service